# Failed sql statement who had sales on more than 1 product

Tags: t-sql

I have a 3 different table as SALESMAN, SALES, PRODUCT. This is what i try to do I must list total sales for each product for each salesman who had sales on more that 1 product

These are my tables and its coumns

```
Product table --> product_id,product_name, price 
Salesman table --> Salesman_id, Salesman_name
Sales table --> Sales_id, Salesman_id,Product_id, quantity


SELECT a.Slaesman_name, p.Product_name, t.quantity FROM SALES t
inner join SALESMAN a on t.Salesman_id =a.Salesman_id 
inner join PRODUCT p on t.Product_id = p.Product_id
```

these is my sql so far but i need to show records only had sales on more than 1 product how should i continued ?

Answer (score 0):

To find which salesmen sold more than one product, use

```
SELECT Salesman_id 
FROM SALES t
Group By Salesman_id
Where COUNT(Product_id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

because you want total sales , we should use `SUM` syntax and whenever we have sum , there should be a `GROUP BY` syntax for other columns that are not in sum . at last whe would have a `HAVING` because of the condition :

```
SELECT a.Slaesman_name, p.Product_name, Sum(t.quantity) FROM SALES t
inner join SALESMAN a on t.Salesman_id =a.Salesman_id 
inner join PRODUCT p on t.Product_id = p.Product_id
GROUP BY (a.Slaesman_name, p.Product_name)
HAVING Sum(t.quantity) > 1
```